# SqlAlchemy use PostgreSQL timestamptz "AT TIMEZONE" in queries

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a PostgreSQL 11 table with a column of type `timestamp with timezone`, and I want to display this time in various different timezones. In pure PL/pgSQL, I can write a query such as

```
select id, creation_date at timezone 'America/New_York' from "Test" where id=1;
```

which leaves all the nasty time zone handling to the database.
Now, if I map the table in SqlAlchemy (using version 1.4.5):

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@server/database")

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Test"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    creation_date = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
```

I can query the the table using e.g.

```
with Session(engine) as session:
    test = session.scalar(select(Test).where(Test.id==1))
```

but this gives me `test.creation_date` as a Python `datetime` object in UTC. Of course, I can run this query and then convert the timezone in Python, but would it be possible to tell SqlAlchemy to add the `at timezone 'America/New_York'` part to the `Test.creation_date` column when selecting?
EDIT: America/New_York is just an example, the actual timezone will have to be set for each query.

Comment: Do you *always* want the TZ to be America/New_York? Or does it need to be configured when the query is ran?

Comment: It will be configured for each query. Setting the timezone for the entire connection won’t cut it.

Answer (score 4):

If you need the time zone to be this specified with every query, and the fact that according to the [postgresql: Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html)

> The function `timezone(zone, timestamp)` is equivalent to the SQL-conforming construct timestamp AT TIME ZONE zone.

the solution below should work for you:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

expr = func.timezone('America/New_York', Test.creation_date)

test, in_ny = (
    session.query(
        Test,
        expr.label("in_ny"),
    ).filter(Test.id == 1)
).one()
```